# Unable to open DevTools after migrating code snippets

Tags: microsoft-edge, devtools

I think I have corrupted my main profile in Edge (current Ver 103) whilst migrating code snippets from another profile. I used `InspectorFrontendHost.getPreferences / setPreference` to migrate my snippets and it appeared to work fine.

However DevTools will not reopen using F12, CTRL-SHFT-i or right click.
I can see a DevTools tab appear in Browser Task Manager, but no window or tab appears.

DevTools works fine on the same machine in my other profile, even if I have both profiles open in different windows at the same time.

Can I force a reset of the part of the Edge profile that stores snippets without losing the rest of the profile? I am on a work machine so don't have access to elevated priviledges.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I was unable to reproduce this issue. I tried the same function to export/import snippets, but my devtools was still successfully launched. Since a devtools tab is in the browser task manager, you can double click on the tab to see whether it is just unintentionally minimized.

But I'm afraid you cannot only reset the part of your Edge profile that stores snippet. I suggest you doing a browser reset to see if it works. You can go to Settings --> Reset settings --> Restore settings to their default values.

By the way, your snippets are located at a "Preference" file under your profile path. You can go to edge://version to find your profile path.

Comment: Thank you for attempting to reproduce. I tried restoring the profile to default. Using your pointer to the preference file location, I trawled for differences between the profile that wouldn't allow devtools to open and the other one that opened devtools just fine. I couldn't see any values or settings that were obviously out of place (in the vicinity of the snippet contents - it's a 1/2mB file).  Ended up deleting the profile entirely and rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue (i cant open devtools even after browser restart). The reason was that i set wrong value to the preferences at first place (instead of string that contain json - i wrapped it to another string literal - lenght of string was around 127kb). Maybe it was because of length of string because browser parse it like json that consist from one long sting literal. I done it via

```js
InspectorFrontendHost.setPreference("scriptSnippets",JSON.stringify(text)
```

To fix problem - you need:

1. quit browser (because browser constantly rewrite file with preferences)
2. fix manually file with name **Preferences** - file in fact json although extension is absence on it. If you know how to fix json do it - if you dont, just copy value of "scriptSnippets" somewhere to not lost all your snippets!!! As quick fix after you saved broken snippets - just clear value (just try set empty sting literal "") for the property "scriptSnippets"

To find the path to the file use url below and find line **Profile Path** (its path in your os filesystem to directory that contain **Preferences** json file)

```
chrome://version
```

and just in case couple snippets

if you want to download all snippets as json file:

```js
// get string in json format of all snippets
InspectorFrontendHost.getPreferences(preferencesList=>{
    // make blob from json
    const snippets_blob = new Blob([preferencesList.scriptSnippets],{type:'application/json'});
    
    function saveBlobToFile(blob, filename) {
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
    
    saveBlobToFile(snippets_blob, `snippets_from_chrome_${new Date().toLocaleDateString().replaceAll('/','_')}.json`)
});
```

to upload snippets from json file use:

```js
const input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'file';
input.style = 'position: fixed; z-index: 100;';
document.body.prepend(input); // input will appear at initial devtool window that was opened first

input.addEventListener('change',function (event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    file.text().then(text=>{
        InspectorFrontendHost.setPreference("scriptSnippets",text);
    })
})
```